# Different buttons go to the same screen, how to set them to different screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I made a button with presshandler to go to a different screen, but now if i make a new button they all go to that screen. How do i refer/link the buttons to different screens?

Main home screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {

  const pressHandler = () => {
    //navigation.navigate('Lesson3');
    navigation.push('Lesson3');
  }
  const pressHandler1 = () => {
    //navigation.navigate('Lesson1');
    navigation.push('Lesson1');
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text style={globalStyles.titleText}>Lessons Japanese 1</Text>
      <Button title='Lesson 1' onPress={pressHandler1} />
      <Button title='Lesson 2' onPress={pressHandler} />
      <Button title='Lesson 3' onPress={pressHandler} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

screen the button needs to go to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Lesson3({ navigation }) {

  const pressHandler1 = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text>ReviewDetails Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you add a console.log in your two pressHandler funtions, which one is getting called?

Comment: The Lesson 3 is getting called everytime  so i tried to make a second presshandler for the lesson1 and clicking does nothing for that one

Comment: But does the second pressHandler function get called or not? If it gets called, there is some issue in the navigation object, if it's not being called there is some issue in this component.

Comment: how do i insert the console.log in

Comment: i got it the lessons do get called in the console log, so when i press lesson1 the text lesson 1 shows up and also for lesson 3

Comment: Sorry, do you mean "click lesson 1 = text for lesson 1 AND lesson 3" or "click lesson 1 = text for lesson 1, click lesson 3 = text for lesson 3"?

Comment: the second one.

Comment: Seems you figured it out, but this is a good way to debug where the issue is, by really following your code path you can see that the problem can't be in this component, so you start to look somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive got it figured out i missed a import in my main homestack.js now it works how i want it 2

import Lesson2 from '../screens/Lesson2';